# Reference generated .NET assembly in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, build, roslyn

In my .NET application, I use a plugin mechanism. Users can develop plugins and use them in the application. Each plugin will be a separate .NET library.

Plugins may use shared functionalities defined in another .NET library (e.g., interfaces or data types). However, using these shared functionalities can happen through different usage patterns. My application addresses this by inspecting the shared libraries and generating specialized consumer libraries for each usage pattern using Roslyn. The workflow usually looks like this:

1. The developer defines the shared functionalities and compiles them into a base assembly (DLL).
2. The developer feeds the base assembly into the application.
3. Based on the base assembly, the application generates consumer libraries with custom types for every usage pattern (also as a compiled DLL).
4. The developer references one of the generated consumer libraries and uses the types defined therein in the plugin project, depending on the usage pattern the plugin requires.

This works quite well, but compiling the plugins could be more comfortable for the developer. Switching between Visual Studio, the application, and back seems like an unnecessary complication given that the shared base assembly and the plugins are usually two projects in the same solution.

What I would like is this: The shared library is defined as a .NET project as usual. The plugin is a project in the same solution. Is there a way that allows the plugin project to reference the generated consumer libraries without actually having them in the solution so it can be compiled? Maybe through a Visual Studio extension that temporarily generates the consumer libraries using the same mechanisms the application would use?

Note: This question is not about running the application or plugins or about resolving references at runtime. The question is about compiling the plugins without having to explicitly generate the consumer libraries and the types contained therein.

Comment: Have you considered a DI framework? VS uses MEF internally to address what I believe to be exactly the problem you're describing, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @Drew - Maybe you're seeing something I am not. I don't think DI frameworks would help here because the types are just not defined yet. If we look at the code lifecycle, it looks like this: After shared functionality compilation, we only have the base assembly. We then need to switch to application execution to generate another set of assemblies and can then proceed to plugin compilation, where we can use the generated assemblies and types. I would like to merge shared functionality and plugin compilation and skip application execution entirely in this context.

Comment: @NicoSchertler, it looks that source generation could help you. Please check out the blog post: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/

Comment: @Vladimir: That looks really useful. Will take a closer look. Thanks a lot for mentioning it.